# shiny variables avoid Calculate

Tags: r, shiny

I use Shiny app for DBSCAN, I have a lot of sliderInput, let the user choose

But because of the large data, a DBSCAN will wait a few minutes

Do not know how to avoid double counting?

I have tried to use isolate, it does not seem to perform

Program Description

The user selects sliderInput's eps and minpts in the UI and presses the calculation

server will perform

```
db <- isolate (dbscan (dtdb, eps = input $ dbeps, minPts = input $ dbminpts))
```

Because dbscan wait a while, I hope the results come out

The user adjusts the `slider1` and point of `sliderInput` in the UI and does not recalculate dbscan

Instead, recalculate the map and display `ggmap (map) + point`

Unless dbscan `eps` and `minpts` have changed, and the button is pressed

But now no matter how, will be implemented

```
db <- isolate (dbscan (dtdb, eps = input $ dbeps, minPts = input $ dbminpts))
```

But also wait a few minutes to have the result, I do not know what else can be used?

```
ui <-label = "data",    
     sliderInput("eps", label="EPS",
     min = 0.01, max = 0.09, value = 0.01),

     sliderInput("minpts", label="MinPts",
     min = 10, max = 50, value = 10),

     actionButton("goButton", "Calculate"),

     sliderInput("slider1", label="MAP",
     min = 5, max = 20, value = 16),

     sliderInput("point", label="point",
     min = 0.5, max = 5.5, value = 3, step = 0.5)

server <-output$distPlot2 <- renderPlot({

    map <- get_map(location = c(lon = -74.0028885, lat = 40.7310282), zoom = input$slider1)

    if(input$goButton == 0){
      return(ggmap(map ))
    }

    input$goButton

    dtdb <- dt.All.data[,3:4]

    db <- isolate(dbscan(dtdb, eps=input$dbeps, minPts=input$dbminpts))

    point <- geom_point(data = dtdb,aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude),col=db$cluster+1L,size = input$dbpoint)

    ggmap(map) + point 
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi the problem is that you put all the calculations in the same reactive context e.i. the `renderpolot`. Try to make chains of reactive expressions. That way is it much easier to controll when what is recalculated. I would try something like this

```
server <- function(input,output,session){

  map <- reactive({
    map <- get_map(location = c(lon = -74.0028885, lat = 40.7310282), zoom = input$slider1)
  })  

  points <- eventReactive(input$goButton,{
    dtdb <- dt.All.data[,3:4]

    db <- isolate(dbscan(dtdb, eps=input$dbeps, minPts=input$dbminpts))

    point <- geom_point(data = dtdb,aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude),col=db$cluster+1L,size = input$dbpoint)
  })

  output$distPlot2 <- renderPlot({


    ggmap(map()) + 
      if(input$goButton == 0){
        points()
      }

  })

}
```

No you haven't supplied any test data therefore I haven't tested the code to see if it works 100% but it sould give you some Idea of how you can structure your code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, I will study reactive, It will be very helpful for me

Comment: @KenChen happy to help out. If you found the answer helpful please accept and/or upvote. It helps future readers to find good information quicker.